# Memory for large data in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, large-data

PDO seems like a little tricky, but I have a large database and I'm getting this error,

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 100663296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 256 bytes)
```

When using,

```
fetchAll()
```

What is the best way to solve it?

Comment: I'm almost afraid to ask - how large is your database?

Comment: If you need to load your entire db to PHP array.. the design of your app is most likely flawed. Increase the memory allowed to the PHP script, try to use `SplFixedArray` if you know the amount of rows you'll get or simply re-think the feature you're doing and do it without loading everything to the memory.

Comment: Tiny then thats not at all large ... how many columns and field-types/sizes? and if it's down to that then you're table(s) drastically need normalised!

Comment: What are you storing in there? I'm currently working with databases with a couple of million entries and haven't had any issues with memory, though admittedly I don't have much in there.

Comment: It's broken database design then.

Comment: No such thing... to build any application to any degree of usability you *must* know how to design a database, as well as the code to manipulate it. OK, lets see you're table definition (create statement) and we can see how to break it down.

Comment: You cannot fix the broken db design using PHP. Period. If you are trying to do that, then that's simply wrong.

Comment: You're only answer is to give it more ram or normalise it out. As the rows are (seemingly) so huge they take up too much data. Simple as that.

Comment: If the "problem" is "my data can't fit into PHP array" then you have 2 options. Option 1) Increase the allowed memory for PHP and pray you have enough, Option 2) Don't put so much data into the memory. If the "problem" is not the memory storage but bad approach to the problem, then you need to tell people what you're trying to solve and how you're doing it. Apparently, having a table that might have tons of columns and needs to be loaded into memory is not a good approach. Proceed as you like from now.

Comment: @N.B. - Amen. We have done all we can to guide you, personally I have been working with PHP (among many others) for 12+ years so I think I know a little bit.

Comment: Heh... also 'I'm not the database designer' if this is for a company and not a personal project, alleged database designer needs shot.

Comment: Congratulations, I hope you have a successful and fun time coding and solving problems.

Comment: according to this http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#104609 comment on php.net try to use fetch() with while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily allocate extra memory using:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '750M');
```

The actual problem is PHP itself not PDO per-se... the PHP Array it's creating is too big... try above... obviously 750M is a lot but ya get the idea!

You will probably fine in php.ini memory_limit is 128M by default ... resulting in the error you're getting when the script execution over all exceeds this.

**ALTERNATIVELY**:

(as per my comments) - Only fetch what you can display for the user, i.e. implement some form of Paging.

A great combination is using jQuery Datatables and server-side pipeline of data. I.e. it will fetch from DB for each page as requested.

**ALSO**:

Make sure your schema has been properly designed and normalised and not just got 100's of columns!

Comment: I'm looking for a better solution as @Kemil Kokot said.

Comment: And what is the better solution? Either allow for more memory or don't save so much data to the PHP's array, it's as simple as that.

Comment: A better solution is making sure you only fetch what you can display comfortably to the user too. Will a user want to scroll 1000's of rows? :) ... assuming it's for display that is. It will result in a quicker query to run too.

Comment: Actually I see this was the solution, but just wanna know a answer why you down voted me, any reason?

Comment: @itsme - your question was *probably* downvoted because you asked for a solution for exceeding the memory limit, but in the comments you actually explained *why* you're exceeding it. Exceeding the limit is easy to fix, the *why* part isn't. Since the question doesn't highlight the issue with PDO causing the memory problem, it's not really useful for anyone and it's not the cause of your problem, only the result. Therefore, it's a really bad question. Also, no idea why this answer was downvoted (and only once), since it's a proper answer to the original question.

Comment: @N.B. cheers for support... and it's times like this I wonder why I bother sharing 12 years experience at all :)

Comment: @Brian - no probs, there's a saying about situation like this but I don't want to insult anyone with inappropriate comments. No use forcing someone to do things properly when they're determined to do it their own way. Smart people learn from their mistakes, wise people learn from other people's mistakes :)